# Can I create Trigger on mysql base

Tags: mysql, triggers

I was trying to create a trigger on mysql database but on error happened. My code is:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER alterTable AFTER INSERT ON mysql.general_log 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
     IF NEW.argument LIKE "ALTER %" THEN
         INSERT INTO altersLog (queryAlter) VALUES (NEW.argument);
     END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

When I run this code, on error is showed:

```
SQL Error (1465): Triggers can not be created on system tables
```

Can I create triggers on mysql database?

Thanks

Comment: The error seems self explanatory.

Comment: I suspect that the limit is there to prevent corruption of those tables. If a trigger failed it could prevent sql from performing some 'essential operations'.

Comment: The answer is in your question...